# unity: read image pixels

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im trying to read how many pixels my image has. It's working fine however it's returning a wrong pixel number. The image has 400 pixels in total and im only getting 256.

```
private void Pixelreader()
{
    // Load image
    Texture2D image = (Texture2D)Resources.Load(texture);
    Debug.Log(image);

    // Iterate through it's pixels
    for (int i = 0; i < image.width; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < image.height; j++)
        { 
            Color pixel = image.GetPixel(i, j);

            // if it's a white color then just debug...
            if (pixel == Color.white)
            {
                Debug.Log("Im white");
            }
            else 
            {
                Debug.Log("Im black");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

it is printing 148 for white and 108 for black.. 148 + 108 = 256. So there are alot of pixels missing. Any idea why its not reading the full image which is 400 pixels?

Comment: Where exactly is it printing these numbers?

Comment: in the console, Im using debug.log

Comment: I meant where in your code. From what you've posted, all you are printing is either "Im white" or "Im black", and you aren't doing any counting whatsoever. So where are your numbers coming from?

Comment: @Abion47 "it is printing 148 for white and 108 for black.. 148 + 108 = 256" He just counts up the logs.

Comment: Pretty sure you're counting wrong or the image is not of the resolution you believe. A quick test of this code shows it loops through every pixel of an image without issue and counts correctly.

Comment: How can i map a 3d object to behave depending if the pixel is white or not?

Comment: What are `image.width` and `image.height` when you debug?

Comment: @Alex you should use `Debug.Log("I'm not white")` in the `else` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
var whitePixels = 0;
var blackPixels = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < image.width; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < image.height; j++)
    { 
        Color pixel = image.GetPixel(i, j);

        // if it's a white color then just debug...
        if (pixel == Color.white)
          whitePixels++;
        else 
          blackPixels++;
    }
Debug.Log(string.Format("White pixels {0}, black pixels {1}", whitePixels, blackPixels));
```

Pretty sure your output lines are just being truncated.

BTW, "GetPixel" is notoriously slow, but that's another story.

Comment: what can i use instead of GetPixel then ?

Comment: `GetPixel` is very slow for `Bitmap` objects, but we aren't dealing with `System.Drawing`. This is Unity, and the "image" is a `Texture2D` object, not a `Bitmap`.

Comment: No matter what you have an unnecessary function call, four bounds checks, two multiplications and some additions  - on each pixel. Negliable for small textures, but just pointing it out. I'd go for GetPixels instead.

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue is that the rest of the pixels are not black or white, just a small tint that the eye can not see.
Try debugging image.width * image.height to get the pixel count of the image.

**EDIT:** You should probably take a look at the max size inside the inspector of the image. It may be locked on 256.

[image: Max size inside inspector of image.]

~ Menno

Comment: He only tests if the pixel is white, every other pixel (white or not) is counted as black since it's just an else statement.

Comment: Oh yeah totally overlooked that. weird.

Comment: where can i see the max size?

Comment: @Alex Added screenshot.

Comment: the image.width and image.heigh is returning 16 x 16.. but the artists made sure it's 20 x 20 . is unity overiding something?

Comment: @Alex It's a general rule that the width and height of textures be a power of 2. Unity is probably performing the conversion automatically.